# How to make Blender respect object viewport visibility when appending or linking?

Tags: 3d-view, linked-data, collections, append

When you link or append a collection to a file, all objects become visible in a viewport, even if they were originally hidden in source file. Strangely enought, render visibility is respected, while viewport visibility is not.

This is a huge problem when you append collection containing complex scene with thousands of different small objects.

How to fix that? Is it possible to append or link objects and Blender respecting souce file visibility setting? I use Blender 2.8.

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure you saved the file before appending from it? Or does it not change the outcome?

Comment: I was observing the same problem with a complex scene with nested Collections, and was planning a Right Click-Select request, but upon doing some smaller tests I've seen it behave correctly, too. I suspect this might be a bug, so, I will try noting it as such at developer.blender.org and see what's their response.

Answer (score 1):

**It's confirmed as a bug**: I sent a sample project with many combinations of Outliner toggles' settings that, on appending, failed to be correctly copied here and there in a seemingly random fashion. Blender's developers have opened a bug case at https://developer.blender.org/T102527

EDIT: devs say toggles' settings are Scene view data (and you could have several Scenes in the project file of origin, each with different settings), not inherent Collection and enclosed items' properties.

So, from a logic perspective it doesn't make sense to copy them (although from an usability and expectations one it is an obvious problem).

Now, what I still see as a bug is the fact that, instead of a default set of toggles' settings, Blender seems to assign random ones. I'm insisting on that.

Comment: If we read the conversation on that report, it's actually confirmed as not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "Disable in viewports" icon : the one that looks like a monitor, not the one that looks like an eye.

[image]

It is a property of the object, and carries over when it's linked into another file, whereas the eye is a toggle specific to the current viewlayer.
Since there can be many viewlayers with different values to this toggle in a given blender file, there is no telling which one to use when appending/linking.